# Java: Overriding an AspectJ getter methods

Tags: java, aspectj

There are some properties which are being injected to JSON entity classes. I am not able to find way to override them or any way to change their return type etc.

Comment: Have you tried to override them in your *.java file?

Comment: Can you ask any more imprecise? You do want help, do you not?

Comment: We need a code snippet at the very least.